# How to executing C++ programme

Tags: c++

I have a simple C++ programme that works fine on Linux, but when I try to execute it on Windows it gives me something like this:

> the NTVDM CPU hase encountered an illegal instruction CS: 055 IP: 0185 OP: of 00 00

this is the code of the programme:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    do {cout<<"Enter 2 OR 3 : ";cin>>n;} while (n<2 || n>3);
    int b;
    cout<<"Enter the number of characters : ";cin>>b;cout<<endl;
    char t[b];
    cout<<"Enter your characters : ";cin>>t;cout<<endl;
    string TA =t;
    if(n==2) {
        for(int r=0;r<b;r++){
            for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
                 cout<<TA[r]<<TA[i]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(int r=0;r<b;r++){
            for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
                for(int k=0;k<b;k++) {
                    cout<<TA[r]<<TA[i]<<TA[k]<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"All Right Reserved ©"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically this code isn't legal because of `char t[b]`, `b` is not `const`.

Comment: @awesomeyi - that's actually debatable. On GNU C/C++, that works perfectly fine and is allowed. On Visual C/C++, declaring a fixed size array from a non-cost variable is not allowed. I think the latest standards permit it, but it's not implemented by the Microsoft compilers.

Comment: @selbie no, it's not debatable. There are no variable-length arrays in C++. There's no such thing as "C/C++" either -- don't confuse/mix the two languages. VLAs are legal C99, but aren't (and never were) legal standard C++.

Comment: _'but when I try to execute it on Windows'_ How did you _execute_? Which toolchain was used to compile your code for windows?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between EXE and ELF executables?

Comment: i compile the programme in linux to EXE , but when i try to run it on windows it gives me that error , can anyone tell me how can i run it , or modify the code to be run on windows

Comment: You are not being clear - are you tryomg to run the Linux compiled file on Windows (that won't work) or have you compiled this code on Windows using a Windows compiler (you need to do that)?

Comment: @Clifford i compiled file on linux and i try to run it on windows . is that the problem why it doesn't run

Comment: @Clifford cross-compiling on Linux for Windows *is* possible with mingw.

Comment: How does C99 VLA work with cdecl?

Comment: @AndrewMedico:  Of course it is but it's a moot point in this case since that is not what is happening.

Comment: @user3504605 : Yes of course that's the problem!  You cannot run native code for one platform on another.  Apart from OS linkage issues, the executable file formats differ.  It is not normal either to use a .exe extension on a Linux executable (not least to prevent Windows from trying to execute it).  Linux executables have an executable attribute flag.

Comment: @selbie :  That's not pretentious, its *precise*.  A different compiler (or the same one with different options) will reject this code, and he'll be posting a question about that then.  If you choose to use a compiler extension, you should at least be aware that you are doing so, and thereby affecting portability, which after all is at issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that variable length arrays are not supported in ISO C++ and presumably allowed here by extension in GCC, you start with a buffer overrun: the array `t` should be at least `t[b+1]` long, and even then you are trusting the user not to enter more characters that they promised.

Since you then assign `t` to a `std::string` (`TA`), why would you not just read the input directly into `TA` which is intrinsically safe (not to mention valid ISO C++)?

```
string TA ;
cout << "Enter your characters : " ;
cin >> TA ;
```

Comment: but what is the solution

Comment: @user3504605 He posted it. Use std::string to store input.

Comment: Well it seems the solution to the problem you were asking about is to compile your code for Windows with a Windows compiler, but the code was incorrect and dangerous in any case on Linux or Windows.  Install a suitable compiler on your Windows machine and build the code on and for that platform.  It is possible to cross compile, but hardly worth the effort, and only complicated debugging.

Comment: @Clifford i didn't understand anything , can you please modify my code and give me the correct  code that do the same thing that my code do ,  of course if you have time please .

Comment: I have already done that - the three lines in the answer replace your input to `t` and assignment to `TA`.  But the code is not your primary issue - have you yet compiled this code on or for Windows using a Windows compiler?